# WPF align menu items

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I want to align menu items to vertical center. But VerticalAlignment doesn't work and finally it's looks like

```
<Menu Background="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource m_menu_Menu}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="PlusCircle" Style="{StaticResource m_top_menu_materialDesign_Farm}" Height="43"  Width="45"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="m_addWork" Header="{DynamicResource loc_menu_top_Add}" />
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ChevronDown" Style="{StaticResource m_top_menu_materialDesign_Farm}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Menu>
```

[image]

I want to cool cell selection like, but align and header item selection look awful. How can I fix problem with vertical alignment?

[image]

After some changes i have:

```
        <Style TargetType="Menu"  x:Key="m_menu_Menu">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Roboto"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="materialDesign:PackIcon" x:Key="m_top_menu_materialDesign_Farm">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Style>
<Menu Background="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource m_menu_Menu}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="PlusCircle" Style="{StaticResource m_top_menu_materialDesign_Farm}" Height="43"  Width="45"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="m_addWork" Header="Add" />
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ChevronDown" Style="{StaticResource m_top_menu_materialDesign_Farm}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Menu>
```

But it's looks ugly yet:

[image]

Comment: I feel this is an issue with one of your styles, not the xaml you have sent so far. Could you edit your original post to include each Style and your DynamicResource?

Comment: @ZachR, sure, did it, but still have problem with stretch alignment. If i change vertical alignment to stretch, all items set to top of cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my main issue with MenuItem.Header and inner StackPanel. Code:

```
    <Style TargetType="Menu"  x:Key="m_menu_Menu">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Roboto"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock"  x:Key="m_top_menu_TextBlock_Farm">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Roboto"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 10 0"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="materialDesign:PackIcon" x:Key="m_top_menu_materialDesign_Farm">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Menu Background="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource m_menu_Menu}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <MenuItem x:Name="m_addWork" Height="75">
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="PlusCircle" Style="{StaticResource m_top_menu_materialDesign_Farm}" Height="43"  Width="45"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Add" Style="{StaticResource m_top_menu_TextBlock_Farm}"/>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ChevronDown" Style="{StaticResource m_top_menu_materialDesign_Farm}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```